# What happens to Tom in Enter Nowhere?

Tags: plot-explanation, enter-nowhere

In the movie [*Enter Nowhere*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1631707/) (2011) the three characters (Samantha, Jody and Tom) manage to alter their own fates. They change the future in which Jody, Tom's supposed mother, grows up to be a nice girl, and doesn't meet her thief boyfriend, Kevin, with whom she had her son Tom in the first place. So what does happen to Tom eventually? Does he ever get to be born?

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't exist unfortunately. Noticed that when Hans shot him he gone into dust. It means he never born because he said earlier in the movie he is the child of Jody and her thief boyfriend. Apparently they both never seen together at the end but the thief was with other girl. I think the shop is mystical and the safe has something with it. Whenever the shop being robbed the thief have the chance to change their terrible life. That's just my 2 cents.